# Скорость загрузки сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

я начинающий в web'e,написал простенький сайт, проверил его в **PageSpeed**,для телефонов показывает **88**, для десктопов **98**.

**У меня есть пару вопросов:**

1)Возможно глупый, но все же:

Есть ли разница в *скорости*, если подключить **.css** отдельным файлом или же включить его внутри **html** документа в теге **style?**

2)Я не совсем понимаю рекомендации от гугла.

**Вот имитация загрузки страницы:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот рекомендации:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Заранее спасибо!**

Вот сайт, если интересно посмотреть(выложил на тестовый хостинг):

http://cg98404.tmweb.ru

Comment: неплохо попиарился))) по сути - такие показатели в баллах на сегодняшний день недостижимая мечта для половины сайтов-хоумпэйдж, можете пока расслабиться...

Comment: Здравствуйте,я ни в коем случае не парился,просто сайт действительно простой,хотелось бы добиться зелёной зоны(от 90 баллов) для мобильных устройств.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Будет ли разница в скорости..." - А что мешает попробовать оба варианта? Результат будет сугубо индивидуальный для вашего проекта, так как баллы- это совокупность, а не столько-то баллов за такое подключение, а столько-то - за эдакое.
   Гугл рекомендует включать маленькие куски css в тело страницы. Исходя из реальных сайтов (ваш пример - это хоумпага, бесконечно далекая от реальных сайтов), стили ВСЕГДА подключаются отдельным файлом/файлами.
2. "Устраните ресурсы, блокирующие отображение" - это кнопка, нажмите на неё, там все разжевано, причем еще и переведено))) Т.е. берем критическую часть стилей, вставляем в тело страницы, остальное в подвал сайта отдельным файлом.
   В вашем случае достаточно объединить все css файлы в ОДИН, у вас их аж три, нафига??
3. ВСЕ СКРИПТЫ В ПОДВАЛ! Еще и в консоли ошибка - нет джиквери. Хотя джиквери и не нужен - ради вот этого однострочного файла load-animation.js??? перепиши на ваниль!
4. Страничка простейшая, но АЖ три шрифта??? Надо оставить ОДИН! на примере шрифта Roboto - если не указывать необходимые варианты, то грузятся все, там все толщины и плюс наклонное начертание, как говорится, НАЧЕРТА оно вам???
5. В галерее картинки видны в размере 350*525, такие и надо туда вставить, но никак не вчетверо больше 1200 * 1800.
6. забудь про формат png (header-avatar.png)  везде, кроме логотипа и иконок!
7. Жертва стильно-модно-молодежного - текущий логотип в формате svg весит 21кБ, я сляпал такой же в png - вес 2кБ!!!
8. Иконка телефонной трубки в формате svg -**вес полтора мегабайта.** Продолжай в том же стильно-модно-молодежном стиле!!)))

Comment: 7. - 5 килобайт Gzip. 8 - 444 килобайт Gzip. Кроме молодёжности есть отличия в рендеринге на высоких ppi, но в данном случае это не важно.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Очень выручили, все учту.
По поводу иконок: я использовал **.svg** , потому что качество не режется, на мобильных устройствах, **.png** ,например, выглядит пиксельно.

Comment: @Pavel - режется-нережется, но иконка весом  как три страницы это в любом случае  бред. Кто будет смотреть эти качественные иконки, если гугл такой сайт в выдачу вообще не будет ставить? Только пара друзей автора сайта?))) svg  - да, выглядит лучше, но я СУГУБО про иконку телефона, она ужасна как по внешнему виду, так и по весу в ПОЛТОРА МЕГАБАЙТА. Такая иконка в svg  должна весить 20кб максимум, погугли сайты с иконками в конце концов, откуда эта убогая иконка??))

Comment: спасибо! Иконка с бесплатных сайтов)

Comment: @Pavel  вот АДЕКВАТНЫЙ сайт flaticon.com с иконками в любом формате.